# removing stylesheet from base theme

Tags: 8, theming

In our Drupal 8 theme we are using the `classy` base theme. `themes/mytheme/mytheme.info.yml`:

```
base theme: classy
```

Using the information from [drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-theme](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-theme) I am trying to remove some stylesheets from the base theme - but I cannot figure out the right way to do so. For instance, I want to remove the `css/components/form.css` stylesheet from the base theme. So far I tried:

```
libraries-override:
  base:
    css:
      component:
        css/components/form.css: false
```

```
libraries-override:
  core/base:
    css:
      component:
        css/components/form.css: false
```

```
libraries-override:
  core/classy:
    css:
      component:
        css/components/form.css: false
```

None of which is working. Removing the stylesheet with `stylesheets-remove` would work fine - but this is deprecated and I would rather use the new intended way for Drupal 8+.

What is the correct way of removing/addressing/extending a library from the base theme?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's `classy/base`:

```
libraries-override:
  classy/base:
    css:
      component:
        css/components/form.css: false
```

Which is defined in the [`classy.info.yml`](https://github.com/drupal/drupal/blob/8.4.2/core/themes/classy/classy.info.yml#L10).